# Cannot specify the ID of an Element with Java codes

Tags: java, html, jsp

I fetched some data from database, including the id of each row, and now I'm creating some elements, the ID's of these elements must contain the ID fetched from the Database.

```
<%
    //Database Codes...I got the rset...
    while (rset.next()) {
%>
<div id="<%=rset.getString(1)%>" class="messageContainer">
</div>
<%
    }
%>
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Bad value " " for attribute "id" on element "div":An ID must not contain whitespace.
Syntax of id:
An ID consists of at least one character but must not contain whitespace
```

Comment: Looks like you're putting whitespace in the id of the div...strip it from the string.

Answer (score 1):

The ID will need to be URL encoded.

Comment: Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, and spell words like 'you' properly.  It makes text easier to read.

Comment: You didn't give me an answer yet

Comment: No I didn't.  I figured that until you improved your spelling, you did not deserve one.  Now that is taken care of, and moving to your inquiry, I meant *"The ID will need to be URL encoded"*.  What part of that are you having trouble understanding (after searching on the term and reading a few of the top hits)?  Be specific, since I do not intend explaining every word used.

Comment: I managed to decode the meaning of "THe ID will need", but still I can't understand "to be URL encoded".

Comment: You do not understand 'to be'?!? Other phrases I might use there are 'to become', 'to be converted to', 'to be changed to'..  As far as 'URL encoded' see the [1st](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) & [3rd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) hits on the topic.